# Check content of T item C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a multi-select page with the list of projects which opens on button click.

```
SelectMultipleBasePage<Projects> multiPage;
async void OnClick (object sender, EventArgs ea) 
{
    var items = new List<Projects>();
    items.Add (new Projects{ Name="Project1"});
    items.Add (new Projects{ Name="Project2"});

    multiPage = new SelectMultipleBasePage<Projects> (items);
}
```

This page has data of `list T` items which contain `Name` of projects.

```
public class WrappedSelection<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public T Item { get; set; }
    }

public class WrappedItemSelectionTemplate : ListViewTemplateCell
{
    public WrappedItemSelectionTemplate() : base()
    {
        Label name = new Label();
        name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Name"));
    }
}
public List<WrappedSelection<T>> WrappedItems = new List<WrappedSelection<T>>();

public SelectMultipleBasePage(List<T> items)
{
    WrappedItems = items.Select(item => new WrappedSelection<T>() { Item = item }).ToList();
    List mainList = new List()
    {
        ItemsSource = WrappedItems,
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(WrappedItemSelectionTemplate)),
    };      
}
```

But I need to check the project's `name` of `T item`. How can I check it in the following code?

```
private bool CheckProject(object arg)
        {
            var item = (WrappedSelection<T>)arg);
            return 
        }
```

i.e. to check content of `((WrappedSelection<T>)arg)` to return if project's `name` contains "Project1".

Comment: `var item = (WrappedSelection<Projects>)arg);` ? Why is the argument of type `object`? Why not use the type that you are expecting?

Comment: Why not use `bool CheckProject<T>(WrappedSelection<T> arg)`?

Comment: @Igor Yeap, I should use the same type, thank you. Please, copy your comment as answer, and I will mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I check it in the following code?

```
var item = (WrappedSelection<Projects>)arg);
```

But a better solution would be to change the signature of the method so the argument is of the expected type.

```
private bool CheckProject(WrappedSelection<Projects>) arg)
```